# State of Art - Nelson Siegel Modeling

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, stochastic-processes, term-structure

My idea is to work with dynamic Nelson Siegel models(DNS) on my master's thesis. As I am finishing undergraduation this year I started researching on the subject. I wonder what is being discussed in this part of Dynamic Nelson Siegel modeling?

1. The estimation method I´d like to use is the Bayesian. What I could
   do with the Bayesian method to put me in the state of art of DNS
   models.
2. I also saw that there is a discussion of terms of arbitrage and
   non arbitrage conditions. What mathematics needed to understand how
   to include no-arbitrage condition (Stochastic Calculus/Process)? I confess I did not quite
   understand the paper (below) reporting this idea.

   http://www.frbsf.org/economic-research/files/wp07-20bk.pdf (this
   one, right?)

   That would be the type of Dynamic Affine Nelson Siegel models with
   non arbitrage conditions?
3. So  the families of Nelson Siegel models are divided into:

   - Nelson Siegel Dynamic
   - Nelson Siegel Dynamic with non arbitrage conditions
   - Affine Dynamic Nelson Siegel models with conditions not arbitration

As you can see I'm a little lost.

Anyway, any information could be useful to me.

Thanks a lot.